# Copying values from one table to another without knowing column names

Tags: mysql

I need to copy data from one table to another. However, I can't use the regular

```
INSERT INTO table1 (VALUES)
SELECT (VALUES) FROM table2
```

because the columns are created dynamically and there's a good possibility that there's a different number of columns in the tables and that at least some of them don't match.

I need to copy the matching columns data only.
Is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: That's a strange requirement. In a single sentence the answer is `NO`. You should try redefining your requirement properly.

Comment: It's probably going to require querying the schema from system tables and dynamically building a query from that.  I don't know enough SQL to say how easy or difficult that may be, though I suspect the logic may be expressed more clearly in another language such as PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into table1(name, surname, telephone) 
    select fname, fsurname, tel 
    from table2
```

I hope I can understand your question

If column name is a variable

```
insert into table1(name, surname, telephone) 
    select $name, $surname, $tel 
    from table2
```

for find columns name `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable`

Comment: `"i hope i can understand your question"` - I don't believe that's the case, no.  I get the impression that the count of columns is also unknown to the query.  And that the source/destination tables have only a subset of columns to be used, also unknown to the query.

Comment: ***@manowar_manowar***: No. This won't work. You need to find columns in both tables and compare if this T1Cx exists in T2Cx and then use if found. There are other comparisons like data type as well.

Comment: I don't know the names for the columns in either table. Right now I'm hoping there's a simple and elegant way of doing this that I've overlooked.

Comment: if you search by name you can use SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable FROM mydb; with using mysql + php (or another language) . You can find first and secon tables fields and you can compare by name.